# Sum one column if it is between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that has log out times in column B, log in times in column C and then the total mount of time logged out in column D. There is the date this event happened in column A.

What I want is a formula which will search Column A for dates only for a set month so as an example dates form April: `01/04/2015` to `05/04/2015` (`dd/mm/yyyy`) etc. and then calculate the total monthly logged out time using column D.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: sorry just realised i hadn't finished typing the subject. Hopefully the main part of my question expalins everything

Comment: give us a sample data and tell us what is the timestamp format in column B and C and what is it like in column D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `=SUMIFS` is likely the easiest way. Look at this example:

[image: SUMIFS]

Basically, this says, "Sum up `D2:D9` if `A2:A9` are greater than or equal to the date in `G2` *and* `A2:A9` are less than or equal to the date in `G3`."

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sumifs` function to do this:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D12,A2:A12,">="&F2,A2:A12,"<="&G2)
```

[image]

or alternatively you can use `sumproduct`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A12>=F2)*(A2:A12<=G2)*D2:D12)
```